# using socket io to get updates

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i'm using in socket.io to get live updates from database. 
here is my code:

```
 var q = "SELECT * FROM notifications";
 db.query(q, function(err, rows, fields) {
  if(rows[0]) {
   io.sockets.emit('newNotifications', rows[0]);
  }
 });
```

its work, but i want to add `WHERE userid = "+myuserid+"`
the question is how to do this?
i tried to do this with this code:

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
 socket.send({"myuserid":"1"});
 console.log('connected');
});
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to tie a userid to a particular a particular socket. How you do this is dependent on how you're handling [authentication](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing).

Once you have a userid attached to the socket, you have a couple options for getting them individual notifications. The most straightforward is to do as you wanted above. Create a query with a condition limiting the results. You need to do this on a per-socket basis though, so you'll need something like the following.

```
data.watchForNotification = function(userId, fn) {
  //  Please sanitize this and make sure you're not vulnerable to sql injection attacks  
  var q = "SELECT ... WHERE UserId = " + userId;
  data.watchedUsers[userId] = setInterval(function() {
    db.query(q, function(err, rows, fields) {
      if(rows.[0]) {
        fn(rows[0]);
      }
    });
  }, 10000);
}

data.stopWatching(userId) {
  if(data.watchedUsers[userId]) {
    clearInterval(data.watchedUsers[userId]);
    delete data.watchedUsers[userId];
  }
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  // authenticate and set socket.userId

  data.watchForNotifications(socket.userId, function(notification) {
    socket.emit('notification', notification);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    data.stopWatching(socket.userId);
  });
});
```

This will setup an interval that checks every 10 seconds for new notifications and will send those to the connected socket when they come in. It will also stop the database queries for that user if they disconnect. There is a lot of pseudo code and abstraction work going on here, but it should be enough to get you where you want to go.

Comment: thanks for your help, but how the user Id var is defined?
and, what socket.send for?

Comment: How you get your userid is up to your code and how it's retrieved. I'm assuming you're doing some sort of authentication on the user. Typically one of the pieces of data you retrieve when authenticating a user it their userid. You cannot simply pass that userid from the client as you show in your original example or you'll be leaving yourself open to a vulnerability where the connected user could pass someone else's userid and get their notifications.

Comment: The socket.emit code will send the notification to the connected socket. In this case it's the socket with the query and userid associated with it.